# Small issue with R plot - lines() stop before end value

Tags: r, plot

I am in the process of making a nice graph but I encountered an issue with the extremities of the lines I drew. I do not know why R does not plot the lines all the way until maxxx (10 here). You can see on the graph from the code below what I am talking about (I cannot put picture as my reputation is too low), the extremities of the lines stop before 10:

```
maxxx<-10
plot(0,type="n",axes=FALSE,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),ylab="",xlab="")
mtext("TROLOLOL",side=3,cex=3)
axis(1,pos=0,at=c(0,10),labels=FALSE)
mtext("R1 ",side=1,line=0,cex=3)
axis(2,pos=0,at=c(0,10),labels=FALSE)
mtext("R2",side=2,line=0,cex=3)


Given_growth_rates<-c(0,0.3,0.5,1,2,5);


K1<-7
g1<-5.5
m<-0.2
R1_isoclines<-numeric(length(Given_growth_rates))
for (i in 1:length(Given_growth_rates)){
R1_isoclines[i]<-((Given_growth_rates[i]+m)*K1)/(g1-Given_growth_rates[i]-m)
}
R1_isoclines

K2<-10
g2<-7
R2_isoclines<-numeric(length(Given_growth_rates))
for (i in 1:length(Given_growth_rates)){
R2_isoclines[i]<-((Given_growth_rates[i]+m)*K2)/(g2-Given_growth_rates[i]-m)
}
R2_isoclines

for (i in 1:length(R1_isoclines)){
lines(rep(R1_isoclines[i],times=length(R2_isoclines[i]:maxxx)), R2_isoclines[i]:maxxx,             col=i+1, type="l")
lines(R1_isoclines[i]:maxxx,rep(R2_isoclines[i],times=length(R1_isoclines[i]:maxxx)),col=i+1,type="l")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the last four lines of your code by:

```
for (i in 1:length(R1_isoclines)){
    lines(rep(R1_isoclines[i],times=2), c(R2_isoclines[i],maxxx), col=i+1, type="l")
    lines(c(R1_isoclines[i], maxxx), rep(R2_isoclines[i],times=2),col=i+1,type="l")
}
```

[image]

Maybe that does what you expect.

Comment: Because of the function of the ":"-operator, check for example the result of 0.5:10, its last value will be 9.5

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will be more careful with the use of this operator. Have a sweet day :D